# Query of data table to return alias

Tags: python

For a long time I've used Python strictly to get something done even though I knew there was likely a much more "pythonic" way of accomplishing a given task. In the example below I have a table that is saved as a CSV and when I need to return an alias I use the alias function.

```
def alias(old,new):
    frame = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\UserName\Teams.csv', index_col=[0])
    return dict(zip(frame[old],frame[new]))
```

FWIW I know one way of improving speed would be to save the data as a dictionary. The only reason I haven't done so is because it's easier for me to make quick additions/changes by opening the Excel file but that's not a deal breaker. That being said, does anyone have ideas on how to improve on this code? And more specifically, is there potential to make it so I only have to indicate which alias I'm looking to return? For example, right now I have to use this line of code to return the RR value for 'ARI'.

```
alias('TEAM','RR').get('ARI')
>>> 15
```

What would be great is if I didn't have to specify that I'm referencing the 'TEAM' value and instead just indicate that I'm looking to return the 'RR' value for a given team/teams. I feel like this should be possible especially given the fact that there are no duplicates. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

| TEAM | MLB | MLB_ID | RW | RR | DBD | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARI | ari | 109 | ARZ | 15 | Arizona Diamondbacks | Arizona Diamondbacks |
| ATL | atl | 144 | ATL | 16 | Atlanta Braves | Atlanta Braves |
| BAL | bal | 110 | BAL | 2 | Baltimore Orioles | Baltimore Orioles |
| BOS | bos | 111 | BOS | 3 | Boston Red Sox | Boston Red Sox |
| CHC | chc | 112 | CHC | 17 | Chicago Cubs | Chicago Cubs |
| CHW | cws | 145 | CHW | 4 | Chicago White Sox | Chicago White Sox |
| CIN | cin | 113 | CIN | 18 | Cincinnati Reds | Cincinnati Reds |
| CLE | cle | 114 | CLE | 5 | Cleveland Guardians | Cleveland Indians |
| COL | col | 115 | COL | 19 | Colorado Rockies | Colorado Rockies |
| DET | det | 116 | DET | 6 | Detroit Tigers | Detroit Tigers |
| HOU | hou | 117 | HOU | 21 | Houston Astros | Houston Astros |
| KCR | kc | 118 | KC | 7 | Kansas City Royals | Kansas City Royals |
| LAA | ana | 108 | LAA | 1 | LA Angels | Los Angeles Angels |
| LAD | la | 119 | LAD | 22 | LA Dodgers | Los Angeles Dodgers |
| MIA | mia | 146 | MIA | 20 | Miami Marlins | Miami Marlins |
| MIL | mil | 158 | MIL | 23 | Milwaukee Brewers | Milwaukee Brewers |
| MIN | min | 142 | MIN | 8 | Minnesota Twins | Minnesota Twins |
| NYM | nym | 121 | NYM | 25 | New York Mets | New York Mets |
| NYY | nyy | 147 | NYY | 9 | New York Yankees | New York Yankees |
| OAK | oak | 133 | OAK | 10 | Oakland Athletics | Oakland Athletics |
| PHI | phi | 143 | PHI | 26 | Philadelphia Phillies | Philadelphia Phillies |
| PIT | pit | 134 | PIT | 27 | Pittsburgh Pirates | Pittsburgh Pirates |
| SDP | sd | 135 | SD | 29 | San Diego Padres | San Diego Padres |
| SEA | sea | 136 | SEA | 11 | Seattle Mariners | Seattle Mariners |
| SFG | sf | 137 | SF | 30 | San Francisco Giants | San Francisco Giants |
| STL | stl | 138 | STL | 28 | St. Louis Cardinals | St. Louis Cardinals |
| TBR | tb | 139 | TB | 12 | Tampa Bay Rays | Tampa Bay Rays |
| TEX | tex | 140 | TEX | 13 | Texas Rangers | Texas Rangers |
| TOR | tor | 141 | TOR | 14 | Toronto Blue Jays | Toronto Blue Jays |
| WSN | was | 120 | WAS | 24 | Washington Nationals | Washington Nationals |

Comment: I'm not sure you can get a very meaningful review of a two-line function.  But is there a good reason you need to `pd.read_csv()` every time it's called, rather than passing the dataframe as a parameter?

Comment: Also, you introduce your code as "example" - we definitely need _real code, in context_ to be able to review it effectively.

Comment: @TobySpeight Maybe I should've asked this in StackOverFlow. The reason I don't pass the frame every time I need to use the function is because there are a number of instances where I need to return different aliases for teams and I'd rather have not have to type that line every time I need it. Does that make sense? I understand the methodology is off which is why I'm looking for some help.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, a potential bug - you have `alias('TEAM', 'RR')`, but given the structure of the table, you probably want `alias('TEAM', 'RW')`

For a more elegant way of looking up stuff in a dataframe, realise that they are like a 2D `dict`, where one set of keys are the columns, and the other set is the index. Something like `df.set_index('TEAM'); df.loc[team_name]['RW']`, where `team_name` is the team name whose alias you want to look up, would solve your intermediate `dict` problem. You don't even need the `set_index` bit, as you already set the index when loading the CSV file, but setting the index with an explicit column name instead of an column number makes it easier to understand what's happening, and also insures you against some changes in the CSV file.

Rolling it all up,

```
def get_team_alias(team_name, alias_file = r'C:\Users\UserName\Teams.csv'):
    frame = pd.read_csv(alias_file, index_col='TEAM')
    return frame.loc[team_name, 'RW'] # frame.loc[<row_label_in_index>, <column_name>]
```